# How can I change index name that created by kafka-connect with connect config

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to change name of index that has been already created by kafka-connect as a whatever I want.

Here my kafka connector configuration ;

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8084/connectors' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '
{
 "name": "PROXY_HTTP_TRACE",
   "config": {
     "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max": "1",
     "key.ignore": "true",
     "schema.ignore": "true",
     "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
     "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
     "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
     "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
     "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
     "connection.username" :"elastic",
     "connection.password":"password",
     "type.name": "_doc",
     "name": "PROXY_HTTP_TRACE",
     "topics": "PROXY_HTTP_TRACE",
     "transforms":"dropPrefix,routeTS",
     "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
     "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"(.*)",
     "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1",
     "transforms.routeTS.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",
     "transforms.routeTS.topic.format":"kafka-${topic}-${timestamp}",
     "transforms.routeTS.timestamp.format":"YYYYMM"
}
}'
```

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds for that. Would you like to change the index name by changing `kafka-connector-configuration`? 
What is the current index name, PROXY_HTTP_TRACE?

Comment: Yes the index name is PROXY_HTTP_TRACE as like topic name and this index name occurs spontaneously. I couldn't change it with connector configuration Do you have any suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the connector configuration you can use [elasticsearch ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to manipulate the incoming data.

```
#Create an ingest pipeline
PUT _ingest/pipeline/update_index_name
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_index",
        "value": "new_index_name"
      }
    }
  ]
}

#Put default pipeline to existing index
#make sure that your index name is proxy_http_trace. 
PUT proxy_http_trace/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.default_pipeline": "update_index_name"
  }
}

#Push the data
POST proxy_http_trace/_doc
{
  "field": "test"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Musab, thanks for your answer, I think Every time I need to send data, if I create that pipeline is there any way to send data automatically without manually ?

Comment: Hi @Emrahall, you're welcome. `index.default_pipeline` will help you about it. Once you put this pipeline into index settings document will indexed into the desired index.

Comment: You're welcome Emrahall, happy to hear it worked.